# overflow scrolling with no scrollbars

Tags: css

How do I create a div that has a max width/height but instead of having scollbars have nothing yet still be able to scroll? (usually done via mouse wheel, selecting text and moving the mouse down or arrrows down)

I tried hidden but that doesn't let me scroll. The other options either doesn't allow it to have a max hight or puts scrollbars.

Here is a [sample demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dU3bB/). I'd like to have no scroll bar but be able to see eof.

```
<div id=main>
    Text text text text text text text text...
    Text text text text text text text text...
    eof
</div>
```

```
#main {
    max-height: 400px;
    /*overflow: auto;*/
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: @JackPettinger: I was trying to but for some reason SO isn't allowing me to edit my post. http://jsfiddle.net/dU3bB/

Comment: @acidzombie24 Don't *just* paste links to jsfiddle. There's a reason for the message you saw.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: Yes but the code was meaningless. There was no reason to paste it. I only linked so people work on a demo and not start from scratch

Comment: I found this on SO [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515518/css-html-scrolling-text-without-scrollbars)

Comment: @acidzombie24 It's no reason to post stupid workarounds. Other users are taking example from you.

Comment: This sounds like an all-round bad idea for accessibility reasons.  If you hide the scroll bar, how do you know that the content can scroll?  Please don't say you want this so you can implement your own custom javascript scroll bar, your users will start wishing they could hate you to death.

Answer (score 5):

How about pushing the scrollbar into the **hidden** area ?

```
html,
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: -30px;
    bottom: 0;
    padding-right: 15px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 400px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dU3bB/2/).

Example from [SO - Hide the scrollbar but keep the ability to scroll with native feel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635513/hide-the-scrollbar-but-keep-the-ability-to-scroll-with-native-feel).

Answer (score 2):

For web kit engine supported browser(like Chrome) you can use this

```
#main ::-webkit-scrollbar 
{
    width: 0px;
}
```

but for other browser you need to something else.