# firefox scroll bar hidden

Tags: css, styles

How can I hide Firefox scroll bars when overflow:auto?

> ::-webkit-scrollbar { 
>       display:none;  }

I use this code but this only works on Google Chrome.

any help guys? Thank you!

**Updated**

when I used

> overflow:hidden;

my page can't proceed to footer.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="pageWrapper">
    <header></header><!--end of header-->

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>|
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>|
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>|
            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>|
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>|
        </ul>
    </nav><!--end of nav-->

    <aside>

    </aside><!--end of aside-->

    <section>
    </section><!--end of section-->
    <footer>All Right Reserved 2013.</footer><!--end of footer-->
</div><!--end of pageWrapper-->

</body>
</html>
```

my css

```
/*----- Reset ----*/
html, body, div, span, object, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p,
blockquote, pre, a, address, code, img, small, strong,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label{
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:0;
outline:0;
font-size:100%;
vertical-align:baseline;
background:transparent;
}
body{
line-height:1.5;
font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

body,html{
    height:100%;
    background-color:whitemsoke;
}

ol, ul{
list-style:none;
}

/* ---- END OF RESET --- */
#pageWrapper{
    width:965px;
    height:100%;
    margin:auto;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 17px black;
    overflow:hidden;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display:none; 
}
header{
    background-color: #D4E7ED;
    height:200px;
}
nav{
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#003366;
    padding:10px;
}
nav ul li{
    display:inline;
    padding:20px;
}
nav ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:whitesmoke;
}
nav ul li a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
aside{
    width:200px;
    background-color:#666666;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    margin:0 auto -20px 0;
}
section{
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto -20px 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
footer{
    background-color:#003366;
    height:20px;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `overflow: hidden`?

Comment: I'll try that sir, thank you. but there's no way to hide scroll bars in Firefox when using overflow:auto?

Comment: it's not working I can't see my footer :|

Comment: `overflow-x: hidden`. Would be easier to help if we could see your code.

Comment: wait I will edit my post

Comment: [overflow scolling with no scrollbars](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15314553/1763929).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you don't want scrollbars if your page runs longer than the browser window height, and yet needs to see the footer that's below the "fold". Perhaps you can explain further?

Comment: @VKen bro, in firefox it displays 2 scroll bars if using overflow:auto the scroll bar for your browser and a scroll bar in div

Comment: Well than, as far as I can see you really want the footer outside the viewable area but don't want to see scrollbars. Not sure, if this is a very good idea, but however. In this case I would go for Vucko's solution.

Comment: @Vucko bro it drags my div from center to right.

Comment: @CarloAdap because it's positioned `absolute`. Put everything in a `relative` div and it should work.

Comment: @VKen it's but look at the box shadow when scrolling.

Comment: Hmm, could you explain what is the final design/interaction you're trying to achieve? From my understanding, maybe you want scrolling in the `aside` and `section`? Don't set scrolling in the `#pageWrapper` wrapper and you won't have double scrollbars on the right. I'm not sure where the box "shadow" is. I'm guessing the white bar below the `footer` can be solved by not setting `height`, use `line-height` instead. http://jsfiddle.net/kjAWd/2/

Comment: sorry to bother you guys.! thank you for replying here in my question. god bless!

Answer (score 17):

I didn't find anything specific to Firefox.  I have also been looking for an equivalent to `::-webkit-scrollbar { display:none }`.

What I did find, however, is a generic cross-browser solution:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        Some content...
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.outer {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.inner {
    margin-right: -16px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
</style>
```

The scroll bar is hidden by the parent div.

This requires you to use `overflow:hidden` in the parent div, but otherwise works like a charm.

Comment: If you choose this option take in consideration scrollbars have different sizes on each browser, pay special attention with touch screen devices.

Comment: It deosn't work on FF 56 when inner div content is longer than screen width

Comment: Tweaking the margin is a great workaround for this (note that if you want to hide the horizontal scrollbar then use  margin-bottom: -17px;). Personally I would use 17px rather than 16px because I think that is the scrollbar width/height.

Answer (score 5):

In **firefox 64**, if you want to hide scroll when you have `overflow:auto` you can now do `scrollbar-width: none;`! Woop woop! [Here are the relevant docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-width) (*browser support is show at bottom of page*).

Below is a **css only solution** that will hide your vertical and horizontal scrollbar in firefox (*tested in v64 & firefox dev edition v65.0b8*). **Hint**: *try vertical and horizontal scrolling on the blue div*.

```css
div {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 80%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, cyan, blue);
  white-space: no-wrap;

  /* the line that rules them all */
  scrollbar-width: none;
  /* */
}

span {
  width: 200%;
  height: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, green, yellow);
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<div><span></span></div>
```

Comment: it is an experimental feature! So it needs more time to be approved

Comment: Underrated comment, this actually resolves the issue with Firefox. I know this is old, but thank you!