# How to hide scrollbar in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox

I just found out how to hide the scrollbar in Google Chrome, I did it with this code:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }
```

The only problem is that this doesn't work on Firefox. I tried many ways to do it but it still doesn't work.

Comment: doesn't seem like a good idea to do it that way. use css overflow hidden on html, body and use a wrapper div with 100% height and width.

Comment: This might be a little too obvious, but have you tried -moz- for Firefox?

I agree with abhitalks though, this doesn't seem like a great way to do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394065/firefox-scroll-bar-hidden

Comment: one working solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820304/hidden-scrollbars-in-firefox-allows-scrolling-but-just-no-scrollbar

Comment: Firefox has a recommended [extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/custom-scrollbars/) for customizing scrollbar where you can set scrollbar width to hidden.

Answer (score 175):

You can use the `scrollbar-width` rule. You can `scrollbar-width: none;` to hide the scrollbar in Firefox and still be able to scroll freely.

```
body {
   scrollbar-width: none;
}
```

Comment: This works on latest browser, but please note that this is still an [experimental feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-width). Also, keep in mind that this property should be used with the element that is producing the scrollbar. For example, if you are using Angular Material's `md-content` then, the body does not produce the scrollbar, rather the `md-content` element does. Hence, `body { scrollbar-width: none; }` will not work, but `md-content { scrollbar-width:none; }` will.

Comment: Ah! Finally something like this!

Comment: it has `170` ups, but still did not work for me! Why god, why!

Comment: @DeepakYadav what browser and OS were you testing on?

Answer (score 37):

To hide scroll bar on Chrome, Firefox and IE you can use this:

```
.hide-scrollbar
{
    overflow: auto;
    -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE 11 */
    scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox 64 */
}
```

Answer (score 20):

I was able to hide the scrollbar but still be able to scroll with mouse wheel with this solution:

```
html {overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;}
```

Download the plugin https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel and include this function:

```
jQuery('html,body').bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
    this.scrollTop = (scrollTop + ((event.deltaY * event.deltaFactor) * -1));
    //console.log(event.deltaY, event.deltaFactor, event.originalEvent.deltaMode, event.originalEvent.wheelDelta);
  });
```

Comment: This seems to be equivalent to "overflow: hidden;" and doesn't allow scroll :-(

Comment: Works for me - horizontal scrollbar now hidden in Firefox. Thanks!

Comment: As of Firefox 63, this only works if you set `layout.css.overflow.moz-scrollbars.enabled` to `true` in Firefox's feature settings, making it unsuitable for production use. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#Deprecated

Comment: That didn't do the trick for me however putting scrollbar-width: none; inside html did.

Answer (score 11):

This is what I needed to disable scrollbars while preserving scroll in Firefox, Chrome and Edge in :

```
          @-moz-document url-prefix() { /* Disable scrollbar Firefox */
            html{
              scrollbar-width: none;
            }
          }
          body {
            margin: 0; /* remove default margin */
            scrollbar-width: none; /* Also needed to disable scrollbar Firefox */
            -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* Disable scrollbar IE 10+ */
            overflow-y: scroll;
          }
          body::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 0px;
            background: transparent; /* Disable scrollbar Chrome/Safari/Webkit */
          }
```

Answer (score 9):

I used this and it worked.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-width

```
html {
scrollbar-width: none;
}
```

Note: User Agents must apply any scrollbar-width value set on the root element to the viewport.

Answer (score 8):

For webkit use following:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;  /* remove scrollbar space */
    background: transparent;  /* optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}
```

For Mozilla Firefox use following code:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    html,body{overflow: hidden !important;}
}
```

and if scrolling does not work then add

```
element {overflow-y: scroll;}
```

to specific element

Answer (score 8):

Just in case, if someone is looking for a hack to somehow make the scrollbar invisible in firefox(79.0).

Here's a solution that successfully works for Chrome, IE, Safari, and makes the scrollbar transparent in Firefox. None of the above worked for firefox(79.0) in truly hiding the scrollbar.

Please if anyone finds a way to do it without changing the color, it will be very helpful. Pls comment below.

```
.scrollhost::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.scrollhost ::-moz-scrollbar {
  display: none;
 
}
 
.scrollhost {
  overflow: auto;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-color: transparent transparent; /*just hides the scrollbar for firefox */
}
```

Comment: Try my post it should work without setting scrollbar-color to transparent.

Answer (score 7):

For more recent version of Firefox the old solutions don't work anymore, but I did succesfully used in v66.0.3 the `scrollbar-color` property which you can set to `transparent transparent` and which will make the scrollbar in Firefox on the desktop at least invisible (still takes place in the viewport and on mobile doesn't work, but there the scrollbar is a fine line that is placed over the content on the right).

```
overflow-y: auto; //or hidden if you don't want horizontal scrolling
overflow-y: auto;
scrollbar-color: transparent transparent;
```

Comment: How do you do it in FF70+? `scrollbar-width: none;` doesn't work anymore. I need to hide the scrollbar, not make it transparent.

Answer (score 4):

This is something of a generic solution:

```
<div class="outer">
 <div class="inner">
    Some content...
 </div>
</div>

<style>
 .outer {
 overflow: hidden;
}
 .inner {
 margin-right: -16px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
</style>
```

The scroll bar is hidden by the parent div.

This requires you to use overflow:hidden in the parent div.

Comment: Works, but not reliable as 16px is just an assumed width of scrollbar.

Comment: give credits to the real author @chowey when you copy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394065/firefox-scroll-bar-hidden?lq=1

Comment: It deosn't work on FF 56 when inner div content is longer than screen width

Comment: This fix is solving the problem for FF but have worse side effects in other browsers (cutting the text)

Comment: I can easily see myself using that in all the divs that requires scrolling over my app ...

Answer (score 4):

I got it working for me in ReactJS using `create-react-app` by putting this in my `App.css`:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  html,
  body {
    scrollbar-width: none;
  }
}
```

Also, the `body` element has `overflow: auto`

Answer (score 3):

If you want the scrollbar gone on the whole body and still have functionality, add this under your style tags at the top of your html code. This solved the problem for me.

Reference: https://careerkarma.com/blog/hide-scrollbar/

```
      * {

           scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox implementation */

       }
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update: 2022**

This block of code will hide both the horizontal and vertical scrollbars on Mozilla Firefox.
Tested on `Version 101.0.1`

**index.css**

```
body {
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /** For IE */
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {display:none;}
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  html,
  body {
    scrollbar-width: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

`overflow-y: -moz-hidden-unscrollable;`

Comment: It hides `scrollbar` but stop scroll action. what's the difference between `overflow-y: -moz-hidden-unscrollable;` and `overflow: hidden`. Actually nothing so it is not the right answer. but I give you a vote up. thanks.

Comment: the difference is that the first one hides it only in firefox

Comment: I voted you up but it is so weird for me why you are `-2`? your answer is correct

Comment: The question is how to hide the scrollbars but still being able to let the user scrolls if needed when content overflows, not to completely disable the scroll. the reason for that is that FF scrollbars are ugly and sometimes appear even if content is not overflowing. All other browsers offer simple and elegant css solution for that - may I need to say, even IE!

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything and what worked best for my solution was to always have the vertical scrollbar show, and then add some negative margin to hide it.

This worked for IE11, FF60.9 and Chrome 80

```
body {
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /** IE11 */
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin-right: -20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to hide extension popup option on Firefox, try following

```
  html {
    scrollbar-width: none;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

To hide the scrollbars, but still be able to keep scrolling,

```
  /* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */

* {
-ms-overflow-style: none;
scrollbar-width: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should hide scrollbars for an element on most browsers.

```
.scrollhost::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
 }

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .scrollhost {
        overflow: auto;
        -ms-overflow-style: none;
        scrollbar-color: transparent transparent; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In some particular cases (the element is on the very right of the screen, or its parent overflow is hidden) this can be a solution:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .element {
    margin-right: -15px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

It will not work in Firefox, as the Firefox abandoned the support for hidden scrollbars with functionality (you can use `overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;` in old versions).