# hide scroll bars on mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, scroll

I'm making a web application and i can't seem to get rid of the scrollbars of the menus on Mozilla Firefox. It works perfectly in every browser i tested except for firefox.

Here's the css i use for the scrolls, works in Chrome, IE, Edge and Opera so far, but not in firefox.

```
.main-sidebar{
        position:fixed
    }

    .bar{
        max-height: 400px; 
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .bar::-webkit-scrollbar {
        display: none;
    }

    .bar {
        -ms-overflow-style: none; 
        overflow:hidden;
    }


    html {
        overflow: scroll;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 0px;  /* remove scrollbar space */
        background: transparent;  /* optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
    }
```

.bar is the class of the div where i want the scroll hidden. The menu scrolls fine but it's not hidden on firefox. 
Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
*{
   scrollbar-width: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

At your webkit-scrollbar try this:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }
```

It should work.

Comment: did you try this? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997183/how-to-hide-scrollbar-in-mozilla-firefox

Comment: you mean the overflow hidden in the parent div ?

Comment: use jquery how ? i already tried that command with no effect.