# Using flickity with bootstrap 4 for horizontal cards scrolling (responsive)

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flickity

Can anyone provide an example of this or at least a successful example of  flickity inside bootstrap 4? I am trying to make an horizontal list of cards in a sort of carousel. I want to scroll through them three a time. Using [flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/) seemed interesting, but I have all sort of problems doing so within bootstrap 4. Cards will not be the same size, or will just disappear. I tried using it with and without row/col classes (the grid), just had different issues. 
This is a bit similar to what I want to achieve, except for the scrollbar :
https://www.codeply.com/go/PF4APyGj7F

Comment: In given example you don't need scrollbar to be appear?

Comment: @Pramod I would prefer to have a sort of responsive carousel that would contain the cards, so yeah, no scrollbar. On a desktop it would show 3 of the cards at a time and on a cellphone one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into my problem, I asked on the github of Flickity and someone was able to provide me with a working BS4 example. So from there I knew it was possible to use this plugin with BS4. I just had to find what I was doing wrong.
https://github.com/metafizzy/flickity/issues/742

Answer (score 0):

You can hide scrollbar. Here is the code to hide scrollbar :-

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

Comment: Apparently firefox does not support this very well...[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar)

Comment: See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997183/how-to-hide-scrollbar-in-firefox