# custom scrollbar firefox with css or jquery

Tags: css, firefox, scrollbar

I put a text in a div with a vertical scrollbar. I would like to hide this bar. On Google Chrome no problem but on firefox it is visible. How to do?
thanks

Comment: Can you show some code please.

Comment: @nicowebmaster.  Try putting `overflow: hidden` on the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some usefull tips about your question:

[How to hide scrollbar in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997183/how-to-hide-scrollbar-in-firefox)

In this topic are many answers on this question, i suggest you to choose this one which fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Custom scrollbars are not supported in Firefox or IE/Edge.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp

You can hide it with `overflow: hidden`

Comment: thank you,
I wanted to hide the scrollbar of a text I had overflow-y. The goal was to scroll a text all the way up the screen, like a movie end credits. It's for a client in the cinema.
cordially