# Hide Scrollbars in Firefox and internet explore only using CSS?

Tags: css, scrollbar

Hiding scrollbar doesn't work in Firefox but it works in Google Chrome via the following snippet.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

How can I hide scrollbar using CSS only. I've tried several solutions available online but none of those worked.

Please propose a CSS only solution. Thanks.

Comment: Do you test `-moz-` instead of `-webkit-`?

Comment: Yes it didn't work. I think its old and may be removed(depreciated).

Comment: this is exactly what you want : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997183/how-to-hide-scrollbar-in-firefox

Comment: Only CSS solution is required. This contain jQuery.