# How to hide scrollbar from mozilla firefox?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

CSS to hide scrollbar from Mozilla Firefox as we can hide it from chrome like:-

```
::-webkit-scrollbar
```

Comment: this Question it will helpful for you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997183/how-to-hide-scrollbar-in-firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following

```
<div style='width: 100%;height:300px;'>
     <div style='height: 100%; overflow: auto; margin-right: -15px;'>
          //your overflowing content
     </div>
</div>
```

Here height in parent div depends on your usecase.

The margin-right property in the inner div is the scrollbar width that can be computed from javascript as follows.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute('style', "width: 100%;height: 100%;position: absolute;overflow: auto;visibility: hidden;");
document.body.appendChild(div);
div.innerHTML = '<div style="width: 100%;height: 200%;"></div></div>';
var scrollWidth = div.offsetWidth - div.clientWidth;
div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
return scrollWidth;
```

You have to set the returned '**scrollWidth**' data as negative '**margin-right**' to the child container.

This will work on all browsers.

NOTE: The **margin-right** property should be set **after checking whether the content is overflowing**. Or else you will have some width problems.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways:

```
 body {
          srollbar-width: none
       }
```

---

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {

        background: transparent;
    }
```