# "scrollbar-width: none;" not working in Firefox 71 to hide scrollbars while allowing scrolling

Tags: html, css, firefox

According to [all the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38994837/1005607) on how to hide scrollbars while allowing scrolling, the standard approach is

```
.hidescrollbar {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
.hidescrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none;  /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

But I tried this in Firefox 71 and the style `scrollbar-width: none;` (which is meant for Firefox) doesn't work. In FF 71 I see the scrollbars show up when the viewport is exceeded.

Something has changed (since FF66+?) and [this poster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57383313/1005607) has also raised this issue. His solution is to make the FF scrollbar transparent. But it still takes up space, whereas I need to hide it completely.

Are there any solutions for the latest versions of FF to replace `scrollbar-width: none;`?

Comment: Works just fine here. 71 & 72 on macOs Catalina with all os's scrollbars preferences.

Answer (score 3):

Adding this snippet to both `html` and `body` works on Chrome and Firefox!

```
html, body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

Chrome version: 87.0.4280.88

Firefox version: 84.0.1

Comment: seems like in newer Firefox versions you really need to add the style to `html`. adding it to the `body` doesn't work (anymore).

Answer (score 2):

my solution

```
/* Works on Chrome Version 91.0.4472.106 (Official Build) snap (64-bit), Edge, and Safari */

*::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
}

    /* firefox is the end 
working  in version Version 87.0 (64-bit) */ 

body {
   
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scrollbar-width: none;
}
```

react

"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code by hiding the scrollbar by setting its width and background values:

```css
/* make scrollbar transparent */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
  background: transparent;
}

.container {
  /* IE 10+ */
  -ms-overflow-style: none;

  /* Firefox */
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work -- I see the vertical scrollbars in FF 71. I created a simple page to test this. Your snippet works because StackOverflow automatically adds its own scrollbar to that DIV.

Comment: Try hidden vertical scrollbar using  "overflow-y: hidden" this property of css